# Add dynamic String in ListView in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am able to add strings at run time in ListView. But I am only getting the last string data in the ListView. What is the cause of it? Here is my code.

```
 for (GraphUser user : users) { 
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(user.getName()));
                                                      ArrayAdapter<String> str = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr); 
                                                      lv.setAdapter(str);
                                                      str.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    }
```

Comment: move the adapter code outside the for loop.

Comment: It showing me error that create varialble arr..

Comment: arr is within the scope of for. declare it outside the for loop

Comment: But how it is possible?

Comment: what is not possible?

Comment: I did it. But same problem. Only one data

Comment: If you do it right it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>
    for (GraphUser user : users) { 
        (arr.add(user.getName()));

        }

ArrayAdapter<String> str = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr); 
                                                              lv.setAdapter(str);
                                                              str.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

Comment: You for loop to only fetch data,Setting adapter that much time only gives you costly memory operation.

Comment: ArrayList<String> arr=null;
            for (GraphUser user : users)
            { 
             
             arr = new ArrayList<String>();

                arr.add(user.getName());
                

            }

        ArrayAdapter<String> str = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr); 
        lv.setAdapter(str);
        str.setNotifyOnChange(true);


Same problem...Only one data

Comment: What i am suggesting is,assign memory to your list outside your for loop and use for loop to add data only.You can also put log in for loop to check if you are getting number of data or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should override the Adapter class and use changeList method to change the list :

```
    public void changeList(ArrayList<String>  objects){
        this.objects = objects;
        Collections.sort(objects);
        notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
```

objects: the new ArrayList

you should override the getView method:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_custom_layout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setText(objects.get(position));
        }       
        return rowView;
    }
```

list_view_custom_layout : custom Layout xml file ( contains some layout and a textView: "label" at this case )

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution...Working like a charm...

```
ArrayList<String> arr = null;
                                    arr = new ArrayList<String>();

                                    for (GraphUser user : users) {

                                        arr.add(user.getName());

                                    }

                                    ArrayAdapter<String> str = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                            getBaseContext(),
                                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                            arr);
                                    lv.setAdapter(str);
                                    str.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```